# Syncronizing 'radiogroups' with jQuery

Tags: jquery, event-handling

Let there be two - identical in terms of options - radio groups A and B. I'm trying to guarantee, via jQuery, that if some option is selected in A, then it's equivalent option is selected in B, and the other way around.

My current approach is this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".groupA > input").click(function() {
        $(".tutored-radio > input ").click();
     });

    $(".groupB > input").click(function() {
        $(".online-radio > input").click();
    });
});
```

Note: **each radio button is inside a span**. I didn't assign the class directly to the input because it's kind of hard to do it in an asp.net run-time generated ListItem.

The obvious problem being that **it's an infinite loop**: it clicks an element and triggers the click action, which is to click it again, and so on...

***What are your suggestions to this?*** I do have some ideas, but I didn't mention them because I feel they're too "hacky", but will talk about them if it proves necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say equivalent, what do you mean? Equivalent position/index in the group? Equivalent value?

Comment: I'm interested to know what your 'hacky' suggestions are

Comment: They would be either manipulating the click event to make it not fire the event handler (don't know if it's possible - probably not) or only do the simulated click if the radiobutton is not selected already (not particularly "hacky", but it turns out there is an easier solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rather than click try setting the arrtibute tag.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".groupA > input").click(function() {
      $(".tutored-radio > input ").attr(”checked”, “checked”);
    });

    $(".groupB > input").click(function() {
      $(".online-radio > input").attr(”checked”, “checked”);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say equivalent option, what do you mean? I'll assume you mean `value`

Something like the following will work

```
$(function() {

     $('span:has(input:radio)').click(function() {             
       var $this = $(this);
       var val = $('input:radio', $this).attr('checked','checked').val();
       var group = $this.hasClass('groupA') ? '.groupB' : '.groupA';       
       $(group + '> input:radio[value="' + val + '"]').attr('checked','checked');            
     });

});
```

Here's a [**Working Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ukate)

Comment: Though the value is also equal in "equivalent" buttons, the "definition" of "equivalent" in this context would be "inside a span element with the same class".

Comment: Also, check my comment to my original question about my 'hacky' solutions.